# ¿Cómo seleccionar automáticamente los productos en función de su id?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Actualmente, cuando se carga el editar de una maleta de productos en mi panel, sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar reconoce el nombre y el estado de la maleta en función del id. Sin embargo los productos no los selecciona, y no tengo idea del por qué.

Se supone que debería aparecer así, apenas cargue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
     <div class="container my-5" style="background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Editar Maleta de pedidos -  <?php 
    echo $id; ?></h1>
    <form id="actualizar" method="post" action="actualizar_maleta_pedidos.php">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input for="id_caja" type="hidden" name="id_caja" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <label for="nombre" class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" required value="<?php  echo $nombre ?>">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="estado" class="form-label">Estado:</label>
        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-select" required>
        <option value="">Selecciona un estado</option>
        <option value="Pendiente" <?php if ($estado == 'Pendiente') echo 'selected'; ?>>Pendiente</option>
        <option value="En proceso" <?php if ($estado == 'En proceso') echo 'selected'; ?>>En proceso</option>
        <option value="En tránsito" <?php if ($estado == 'En tránsito') echo 'selected'; ?>>En tránsito</option>
        <option value="En Ecuador" <?php if ($estado == "En Ecuador") { echo "selected"; } ?>>En Ecuador</option>
        <option value="Entregado" <?php if ($estado == 'Entregado') echo 'selected'; ?>>Entregado</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="productos" class="form-label">Productos:</label>
      <script>
function actualizarSeleccionados() {
  var seleccionados = [];
  var select = document.getElementById("productos");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) {
      seleccionados.push(select.options[i].value);
    }
  }

  var inputs = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < seleccionados.length; i++) {
    var idProducto = seleccionados[i];
    var opcionSeleccionada = select.querySelector(`option[value='${idProducto}']`);
    var idProducto = opcionSeleccionada.value;
    var nombreProducto = opcionSeleccionada.text;
    var pesoProducto = opcionSeleccionada.dataset.peso;

    var inputHtml = `<br><div><span>${nombreProducto} </span><input class='form-select' type='number' name='cantidades[]' id='cantidad-${idProducto}' value='1' placeholder='Cantidad'> <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='eliminarSeleccionado(${idProducto})'>Eliminar</button></div>`;
    inputs += inputHtml;
  }

  document.getElementById("inputs-cantidad").innerHTML = inputs;
}


function eliminarSeleccionado(idProducto) {
  var select = document.getElementById("productos");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].value == idProducto) {
      select.options[i].selected = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  actualizarSeleccionados();
}

</script>
<style>
    .eliminar {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
</style>


<select name="productos[]" id="productos" class="form-select" multiple onchange="actualizarSeleccionados()">
  <?php
    require 'config/bd.php';
    $maleta_id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT id_productos FROM maletas_productos WHERE id = $maleta_id";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    $productos_maleta = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $productos_maleta_ids = array_column($productos_maleta, 'id_productos');
    
    
    require 'config/api.php';

    $product_url = "https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=$consumer_key&consumer_secret=$consumer_secret";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $products = json_decode($output);

  
    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $id = $product->id;
      $name = $product->name;
      $weight = $product->weight;
      if (in_array($id, $productos_maleta_ids)) {
          echo "<option value='$id' selected>$id - $name ($weight kg)</option>";
      } else {
          echo "<option value='$id'>$id - $name ($weight kg)</option>";
      }
  }
  
    
    
    
    
  ?>
</select>



<div id="productos-seleccionados"></div>
<div id="inputs-cantidad"></div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#actualizar2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Aquí se agregan las acciones para mostrar el mensaje de éxito con SweetAlert2
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: '¡Actualización exitosa!',
      text: 'La maleta de pedidos ha sido actualizada correctamente.',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 2000
    }).then(() => {
        // Se envía el formulario después de que la modal desaparezca
        $('#actualizar').submit();
    });
  });
});
</script>

<br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar2">Editar maleta de pedidos</button>
     

      <a href="maletas_productos_list.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
    </form>
  </div>
```

La estructura de mi base de datos se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Y por qué se debería ver como dices? Ver capturas de pantalla ayuda poco para este caso. Vamos a centrarnos en el código, pues ahí está el problema. ¿Depuraste los resultados de tu consulta? ¿Arrojan los datos que esperas?

Comment: De hecho, ya los selecciona correctamente pero no entiendo porque no abre los inputs de cantidad... Cuando se hace click los abre, pero la idea es que los abra también automáticamente en esta sección. La salida es: array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "13069" [1]=> string(5) "12124" [2]=> string(5) "12115" [3]=> string(4) "6787" }